# Error from callback function in python websocket: line 346, in _callback callback(self, *args)

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, callback, bots, trading

I used the Gemini websocket code for a BTC feed but a callback error keeps popping up. However, it occasionally does run the code correctly. I have used 'price' and 'quantity' to test the code before I use the actual variables I want.

[Error from running my gemini websocket code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XnOa.png)

Here is the code:

```
import websocket, ssl, json
import _thread as thread
websocket._logging._logger.level = -99

bestbid = {}
bestask = {}

top_of_book = 0
def on_message(self, message):
    global bestbid, bestask
    bestbid = json.loads(message)
    bestask = json.loads(message)
    print("Message received!")
    print("{}    {}".format(bestbid["price"], bestask ["quantity"]))

                   

def on_error(self, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(self):
    print("Connection closed!")

def on_open(self):
    print("Connection opened!")
    def run(*args):
        ws.send(logon_msg)
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logon_msg = '{"type": "subscribe","subscriptions":[{"name":"l2","symbols":["BTCUSD"]}]}'
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api.gemini.com/v2/marketdata/",
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close,
                                on_open = on_open)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that bestbid (bestbuy) JSON object has fields "price" and quantity". Errors most probably are caused by heartbeat or some diagnostic messages.